# buildroot rootfs on arm board

Tags: boot, embedded, kernel-panic, embedded-linux, arm

After building buildroot with Kernelimage and rootfs (jffs2)
i flashed them to my board.

bootargs set to:
mem=64M console=ttyS0,115200 root=/dev/mtdblock1 rw rootfstype=jffs2

Now when i boot i get the following error:

VFS: Cannot open root device "mtdblock1" or unknown-block(31,1)
Please append a correct "root=" boot option; here are the available partitions:
1f00             256 mtdblock0 (driver?)
1f01          261888 mtdblock1 (driver?)
1f02            8448 mtdblock2 (driver?)
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(31,1)

anyone know what went wrong?

best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your kernel configuration. This message means that the kernel doesn't have a driver for what you've told it is the root device. Your command line looks plausible, so make sure you've included MTD block device support in the kernel (not as a module). Make sure you have jffs2 in the kernel as well.

Comment: well i am using a default config which should do fine, the following options are set:

CONFIG_MTD=y
CONFIG_MTD_CONCAT=y
CONFIG_MTD_PARTITIONS=y
CONFIG_MTD_CMDLINE_PARTS=y
CONFIG_MTD_CHAR=y
CONFIG_MTD_BLOCK=y
CONFIG_MTD_DATAFLASH=y
CONFIG_MTD_NAND=y
CONFIG_MTD_NAND_ATMEL=y

Comment: for jffs2 i included
CONFIG_JFFS2=y